# How to list the column names in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with sql server and I was asked to give grant solely to the table column's involved in a query.

So let's suppose I had this query Q to perform an extraction:

```
SELECT 
    A.C1,
    B.C1,
    C.C1 
FROM   
    TABLE1 A 
INNER JOIN 
    TABLE2 B ON A.C2 = B.C2 
INNER JOIN 
    TABLE3 C ON B.C3 = C.C2
```

I had to give `SELECT` permission only to columns:

```
   A.C1
   A.C2
   B.C1
   B.C2
   B.C3
   C.C1
   C.C2
```

Now I have to parse in a boring human way the query, to collect the columns.

Is there a way, some system query way, to "query the query"? A way to put the query Q in input and to get the list of the involved columns in output?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you need to do that in T-SQL? This is typically quite easy through a database driver like JDBC (Java) where you can "describe" the result of a query.

Comment: I need to retrieve the columns belonging to multiple tables that are involved in a query, not the columns belonging to a single table

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you should create a [view](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/views.php) containing the actual restricted result.

Something like:

```
 CREATE VIEW view_name AS
 SELECT A.C1,
      B.C1,
      C.C1 
 FROM   TABLE1 A 
 INNER JOIN TABLE2 B 
       ON A.C2 = B.C2 
          t_line.dbo.is_pagamentorate.parentlink_recid 
 INNER JOIN TABLE3 C 
       ON B.C3 = C.C2
```

Comment: And in conjunction remove full access to the individual tables.

Comment: Good idea, but I've not the permission to create a view!!

Comment: You can't create a view but you can assign permissions to other users? Talk to your dba and have them create the view from the code you provide them or have them give you permission.

Comment: It's always my DBA to give the permission, it's not me. And to create a view I need an authorization.